# How to modify Wordpress Themes on Openshift

Tags: wordpress, openshift

When I git clone my wordpress app from Openshift, .openshift/themes and .openshift/plugins directories contain no file except .gitkepp.

So how can I actually get my themes and plugins so that I can modify them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developers.openshift.com/en/php-wordpress.html) you have two upload options:

1) Using the admin panel ([yourapp]-[yourdomain].rhcloud.com/wp-admin) to upload the themes there (unless you have a scaled app, in which case this method won't work properly as your files will only be uploaded to the current gear)

2) Unzipping the theme/plugin into `.openshift/themes` or `.openshift/plugins` and adding it to git.

If you already have the plugins installed and you used method 1) on a scaled application, you'll need to switch over to method 2) as the files won't be in the git repo.